# ACF update field to null on field change

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am hoping someone could please assist, I need to delete a field when a status goes to complete for a post, below is the code, right now this works but it always changes the field to null when the post updates it doesn’t matter what the status is. I need it to only delete the value when the status is complete.

```
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post_7',10 );
function my_acf_save_post_7( $post_id ) {
$value = get_field( 'status', $post_id );
if ( $value = 'complete' ) {
    update_field( 'project_address_1', null, $post_id );
}
}
```

Comment: I think there's a typo here instead of `if ( $value = 'complete' ) {` it needs to be `if ( $value == 'complete' ) {`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it didn’t work either, it didn’t change the value.

Comment: With this change the field didn’t get changed to null, it didn’t change the field at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

ACF Field - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/delete_field/

```
delete_field( 'my_field', $post_id );
```

Like `delete_field( 'color', 123 );`

Post meta - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_post_meta/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `delete_field( 'project_address_1', $post_id );` instead updating with null value